# What does character mean in R?

Tags: r

I tried out a few examples and I feel that 'character' refers to either a string or an array of strings.

```
> x = 'hello'
> class(x)
[1] "character"

> x = "hello"
> class(x)
[1] "character"

> x = c('hello','world')
> class(x)
[1] "character"
```

Why is it called a 'character'? It confuses me because when I hear the word 'character', what first comes to my mind is something like, char ch = 'a', basically a single character :)

Comment: `character` object is an atomic vector of a certain length. R is vectorized language. Everything in R is a vector, thus `x = "hello"` is a character vector of length one. `x = c('hello','world')` would be a character vector of length 2 and etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character refers to the class of a vector. Character vectors are comprised of strings.

For example, `"a"` and `"apple"` could both be elements in a character vector.

Comment: To add to this - on the question of "a string or an array of strings"; actually R doesn't have the concept of a single, user-accessible strings. When you see "foo" you're not looking at a string: you're looking at a vector of strings, of length 1.